# Does saveOrUpdate() in Hibernate preserve the value of existing fields which are there in DB but not set in the object passed to the function?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Lets say I have table:

`class BirthDay{
     int pk;
     Date birth_date
}`

Now I already have an entry in the DB with say pk=7,year='1-1-95'. Now I want to save a BirthDay object whose pk=7(which is same as the one already in DB), but the other field: birth_date is not set(so by def it will be null). Please help me understand what will happen if I use saveOrUpdate() while saving the object. Will the existing birth_date field value be preserved or will it be set to null as the object that I am passing to saveOrUpdate() has that field set to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on the hibernate - dynamic-update parameter. If it is set to true, your value will not be overwritten by null, but if the parameter is set to false, null will overwrite the value of your database.

[Hibernate - DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html)